# Impossible to update jQuery version from 3.1.0

Tags: jquery, security

PageSpeed Insights is complaining about me using jQuery version 3.1.0 because of security risks.

I've been trying to update my jQuery version with two plugins:

- jQuery Updater
- jQuery Version Control

I have cleared the cache after making the necessary configurations for the plugins, but to no effect. (My Wordpress version is 6.1.1 and all the other plugins are updated)

When I check the jQuery version by typing `jQuery.fn.jquery` in the Developer Console, the version is still 3.1.0

What else can I try to do in order to update the jQuery version so Google regards my site as safe?

Comment: you should not rely on a plugin to update jQuery, if any theme or plugin hardcodes jQuery from a CDN it will not be possible to remove and fix that using a plugin without taking steps that will cripple your page speed scores. You need to identify where the older version of jQuery is coming from, either by a process of elimination, or by reading the code

Comment: thank you. I finally realized, thanks to your answer, that I had included the old version in the footer.php - thanks!

Comment: can you write that as an answer below including what you removed and what you changed it to so that others with this problem can learn?